# Error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression

Tags: java, programación-funcional, lambda

He desarrollado una *Functional Interface* para practicar con lambdas, en los primeros ejemplos me sale bien, pero en el ultimo ejemplo cuando quiero redondear me salta y error que pego al final. `Math.round(n)` me devuelve un **integer con en los casos anteriores (cuando obtengo la longitud del nombre, el cuadrado y el doble).

Concretamente el error está en la línea 36 (está indicada cual es).

```
public class MapperTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// Map names using their length
        System.out.println("Mapping names to their lengths:");//asocia nombre con su longitud
        String[] names = {"David", "Li", "Doug"};       
        int[] lengthMapping = Mapper.mapToInt(names, (String name) -> name.length());
        printMapping(names, lengthMapping);
        
        System.out.println("\nMapping integers to their squares:");            
        Integer[] numbers = {7, 3, 67};
        int[] countMapping = Mapper.mapToInt(numbers, (Integer n) -> n * n);
        printMapping(numbers, countMapping);
        
        
         System.out.println("\nRelacionando cada numero con su doble:");
        Integer[]numeros = {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,245};
        int[] quieroElDoble = Mapper.mapToInt(numeros, (Integer n) -> n * 2);
        printMapping(numeros, quieroElDoble);
        
       System.out.println("\nRelacionando cada numero decimal con su entero mas cercano:");
        Float[]numDecimales = {-0.4f,0.8f,2.2f,9.1f,9.7f,5.6f};
        int[] quieroRedondear = Mapper.mapToInt(numeros, (Double n) -> Math.round(n));//linea36
        printMapping(numDecimales, quieroRedondear);
    }

    public static void printMapping(Object[] from, int[] to) {
        for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(from[i] + " mapped to " + to[i]);
        }
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@FunctionalInterface
interface Mapper<T> {
// An abstract method

    int map(T source);
// A generic static method

    public static <U> int[] mapToInt(U[] list, Mapper<? super U> mapper) {
        int[] mappedValues = new int[list.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
// Map the object to an int
//guarda en mappedValues los valores de list[] que dicte el metodo map cuando se implemente
            mappedValues[i] = mapper.map(list[i]);
        }
        return mappedValues;
    }
}
```

El error que me muestra es:

> R:\PROYECTOS_JAVA\HOW_TO_PROGRAM\Lambdas\src\kishoriSharamExammples\MapperTest.java:36: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
>
> int[] quieroRedondear = Mapper.mapToInt(numeros, (Double n) -> Math.round(n));
>
> possible lossy conversion from long to int
> Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
> 1 error
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: El problema está indicado en el error. Le pides que devuelva un `int` pero el método [`Math.round(Double n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) devuelve un long tal como se indica en la documentación. El método round que devuelve un `int` es el que recibe un `float`! O cambias el parámetro de entrada a float (de hecho, tienes los números declarados como float pero luego en la lambda los tipas a Double n??) o cambias el retorno a long.

Comment: La linea 36 corregida sería la siguiente: int[] quieroRedondear = Mapper.mapToInt(numDecimales, (Float n) -> Math.round(n));